# Check if there's a change in the content of window (Xorg)

Tags: linux, bash, shell, x11, xorg

is there any way I could check (via shell) that there's some change in the context of a window in x11 (xorg)? like

I want to execute a certain script if there's a change in the context of any window in current workspace ( also called as virtual desktops I think ).

Answer (score 0):

Well there is [xev](https://manpages.debian.org/buster/x11-utils/xev.1.en.html), but that only allows you to monitor a single window. There is also [xeventbind](https://github.com/ritave/xeventbind), which allows you execute a command when the resolution changes. It looks like you could modify that program to trigger on other types of events. What type of event do you want to trigger on?

Would something like this work with `xev` & `xprop`?

```
#!/bin/bash

set -o nounset
set -o errexit
set -o pipefail
shopt -s lastpipe

xprop -root _NET_CURRENT_DESKTOP | read -r _ _ desktop
xev -root -event property | while IFS=' ()' read -r type _ prop _; do
    case $prop in
    _NET_CURRENT_DESKTOP)
        xprop -root _NET_CURRENT_DESKTOP | read -r _ _ new_desktop
        if [[ "$desktop" != "$new_desktop" ]]; then
            printf 'Taking a screenshot of desktop (%s)!\n' "$desktop"
            desktop=$new_desktop
        fi
        ;;
    esac
done
```

Comment: Im creating a tag preview for dwm , so whenever I hover over a tag icon ( workspace icon on the bar ) then I want to show a little popup of that tag's content , check this https://github.com/siduck76/chadwm/issues/6